# HttpResponseRedirect and other redirect issues

Tags: python, django, redirect

I wrote simple web application, which can allow users upload and download files and make publications. I'm using django 5.0.1 and python 3.10.2. All worked correctly on my localhost server on my pc, but when i uploaded my project to web hosting (timeweb) i noticed that i cant login into admin panel and my account system. I'm getting infinity page loading and nothing. I have redirection from view of adding publication to the view of this publication after uploading and i'm getting the same issue here (publication still creates, but i cant redirect to it). But i can redirect from here to the older publications, so i think there is something with redirection to recently updated data in database.
my `def add` and `detail` in `views.py`

```
def detail(request, publication_id):
    auth = request.user.is_authenticated

    grade5 = Publication.objects.get(pk=publication_id).grade5
    grade6 = Publication.objects.get(pk=publication_id).grade6
    grade7 = Publication.objects.get(pk=publication_id).grade7
    grade8 = Publication.objects.get(pk=publication_id).grade8
    grade9 = Publication.objects.get(pk=publication_id).grade9
    grade10 = Publication.objects.get(pk=publication_id).grade10
    grade11 = Publication.objects.get(pk=publication_id).grade11

    lettera = Publication.objects.get(pk=publication_id).lettera
    letterb = Publication.objects.get(pk=publication_id).letterb
    letterv = Publication.objects.get(pk=publication_id).letterv
    letterg = Publication.objects.get(pk=publication_id).letterg
    letterd = Publication.objects.get(pk=publication_id).letterd

    letter = (lettera*"А") + (letterb*"Б") + (letterv*"В") + (letterg*"Г") + (letterd*"Д")
    grade = (grade5 * "5") + (grade6 * "6") + (grade7 * "7") + (grade8 * "8") + (grade9 * "9") + (grade10 * "10") + (grade11 * "11")+ " "
    if (len(letter)>1):letter = "вся параллель"
    if (len(grade)>2):grade = "все параллели, "



    
    return render(request, "schoolbase/detail.html",
        {
            "auth": auth,
            "Publication":Publication.objects.get(pk=publication_id),
            "grade":grade+letter,
            "category": Publication.objects.get(pk=publication_id).category_any * "общая" + Publication.objects.get(pk=publication_id).category_olympiad * "олимпиадная" + Publication.objects.get(pk=publication_id).category_educational * "учебная" + Publication.objects.get(pk=publication_id).category_schedule * "расписание" + Publication.objects.get(pk=publication_id).category_menu * "меню столовой",
        }
        )


def add(request):

    
    try:
        newp_name = request.POST["Publication_name"]
        newp_text = request.POST["Publication_text"]
        grades = int(request.POST["grade"])
        letters = int(request.POST["class"])
        categories = request.POST["category"]
        
        
        
        Pre_grade5 = False
        Pre_grade6 = False
        Pre_grade7 = False
        Pre_grade8 = False
        Pre_grade9 = False
        Pre_grade10 = False
        Pre_grade11 = False

        if (grades == 5): Pre_grade5 = True
        elif (grades == 6): Pre_grade6 = True
        elif (grades == 7): Pre_grade7 = True
        elif (grades == 8): Pre_grade8 = True
        elif (grades == 9): Pre_grade9 = True
        elif (grades == 10): Pre_grade10 = True
        elif (grades == 11): Pre_grade11 = True
        else:
            Pre_grade5 = True
            Pre_grade6 = True
            Pre_grade7 = True
            Pre_grade8 = True
            Pre_grade9 = True
            Pre_grade10 = True
            Pre_grade11 = True
        
        Pre_lettera = False
        Pre_letterb = False
        Pre_letterv = False
        Pre_letterg = False
        Pre_letterd = False

        if (letters == 5):
            Pre_lettera = True
            Pre_letterb = True
            Pre_letterv = True
            Pre_letterg = True
            Pre_letterd = True
        elif (letters == 0): Pre_lettera = True
        elif (letters == 1): Pre_letterb = True
        elif (letters == 2): Pre_letterv = True
        elif (letters == 3): Pre_letterg = True
        elif (letters == 4): Pre_letterd = True

        anyy = False
        olympiad = False
        educational = False
        schedule = False
        menu = False

        if (categories == "any"): anyy = True
        elif (categories == "olympiad"): olympiad = True
        elif (categories == "educational"): educational = True
        elif (categories == "schedule"): schedule = True
        elif (categories == "menu"): menu = True
    except (KeyError):
        return render(request, "schoolbase/add.html")
            
    
    else:
        publ = Publication(Publication_name = newp_name, Publication_text = newp_text, pub_date=timezone.now(),
            grade5 = Pre_grade5,
            grade6 = Pre_grade6,
            grade7 = Pre_grade7,
            grade8 = Pre_grade8,
            grade9 = Pre_grade9,
            grade10 = Pre_grade10,
            grade11 = Pre_grade11,
            lettera = Pre_lettera,
            letterb = Pre_letterb,
            letterv = Pre_letterv,
            letterg = Pre_letterg,
            letterd = Pre_letterd,
            category_any = anyy,
            category_olympiad = olympiad,
            category_educational = educational,
            category_schedule = schedule,
            category_menu = menu,
            #Publication_author = request.user.first_name,
            )
        publ.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("detail", args=(publ.id,)))
```

my `settings.py`

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-%esmk3vc)-6xe8(j#=gr7&cf6jurgo#a85xq*e2xqr#+v-d)5r'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'schoolbase.apps.SchoolbaseConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'



MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
#Media
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/schoolbase/index'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/schoolbase/index'
```

my `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView
from .views import logout_view

from . import views

from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

favicon_view = RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/favicon.ico', permanent=True)

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("add/", views.add, name="add"),
    path("success/", views.success, name="success"),
    path("<int:publication_id>/", views.detail, name="detail"),
    path('download/<int:file_id>/', views.download_file, name='download_file'),
    path('logout/', logout_view, name='logout'),
    re_path(r'^favicon\.ico$', favicon_view),
    
    
]
```

my `wsgi.py`

```
import os
import sys

try:
  sys.path.remove('/home/c/cs40246/venv/lib/python3/dist-packages')
except:
  pass




sys.path.append('/home/c/cs40246/public_html/mysite/')
sys.path.append('/home/c/cs40246/venv/lib/python3.10/Lib/site-packages/')

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')



from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

ive tried to replace  `HttpResponseRedirect` to just `redirect` and all stayed the same. I reinstalled django and python, double checked python libraries and nothing. Error logs are empty.

Comment: I solved this problem, technical support said it was mistake on their side and they said to add `import sys
__import__('pysqlite3')
sys.modules['sqlite3'] = sys.modules.pop('pysqlite3')` into my settings.py. After that all worked right.